# Is it possible to make a gradient in left border only?

Tags: css, border, gradient

Is it possible to make a gradient in left border alone in CSS3 and if so how? I know that we can make gradient backgrounds and there are many generators for that, but I am unable to find one that creates the code for a gradient border for left border only.

Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Best regards, Shiv

Answer (score 3):

`border-image` allows you to define an image to your border, the image could be a `linear-gradient()`

> The border-image CSS property draws an image around a given element. It replaces the element's regular border.

[MDN - border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image)

---

`border-image` is a shorthand for all those properties:

- border-image-outset
- border-image-repeat
- border-image-slice
- border-image-source
- border-image-width

Thanks to `border-image-slice`, you are able to apply your gradient on your left border only.

> The border-image-slice CSS property divides the image specified by border-image-source into regions. These regions form the components of an element's border image.

[MDN - border-image-slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice)

The MDN docs provide a great explanation on how to use `border-image-slice`, but if you want your gradient to be applied to the left only, simply add the `0 0 0 1` value to `border-image-slice`.

```css
header {
  max-width: 40ch;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      to bottom, 
      red, 
      transparent
    ) 0 0 0 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code:

```css
#lftGrad{

width:200px;height:200px;border-left:10px solid #ccc;background:#ddd;
border-image:gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ff00ff), to(#ffff00)) 0 10 0 10 repeat repeat;
-webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ff00ff), to(#ffff00)) 0 10 0 10 repeat repeat;


}
```

```html
<div id="lftGrad"></div>
```